# $0 = \sqrt{2}\cos(x) - 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$, why do I have to factor out $\cos(x)$, not to divide by $\cos(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Solve for $x$.
> $$0 = \sqrt{2}\cos(x) - \sin(2x)$$
> $$0 = \sqrt{2}\cos(x) - 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

Here, I thought I could divide all terms by $\cos(x)$ to get

> $$0 = \sqrt{2} - 2\sin(x)$$

But the solution says I need to factor out $\cos(x)$ to get

> $$0 = \cos(x)(\sqrt{2} - 2\sin(x))$$

not to divide by it.

Could you tell me why?

Comment: Short answer: by dividing by $\cos x$ you may be dividing by zero. ($\cos x$ may be zero.)

Comment: Oh that makes sense. But is that THE reason why you can't do it?

Comment: Yes, that is *the* reason. You could alternatively say: either $\cos x=0$, or we can divide through by $\cos x$, giving $\sqrt{2}-2\sin x=0$. But then your solution has to take both of those into account.

Comment: @Peppers Does my answer make sense or do you have further questions?

Comment: Thank you so much. You guys helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\cos x$ term might be also a solution to this equation. If you divide it you'll loose it.

You have $$\cos(x)\cdot (\sqrt 2-2\sin x) = 0$$
Now we have three possibilities:

1. $\sqrt 2-2\sin x = 0, \, \cos x \neq 0$
2. $\cos x = 0,\,\sqrt 2-2\sin x \neq 0$
3. $\sqrt 2-2\sin x=  0 ,\,\cos x = 0$

If you divide by $\cos x$ you will only find zeros for the first case.
You'll loose solutions like $\pi/2+k\pi, k\in\mathbb{Z}.$ If both expressions were zero, you would lose them too since you divided by $0$.

Comment: I'm explaining to my students these equation: I have talk with them that it is important to check if the $\cos(x)=0$ it is solution of the equation. Often when there is not the constant the solution $\cos(x)=0$  or $\sin(x)=0$ not exists. +1

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you were trying to solve the quadratic
$$
x^2+x=0
$$
by dividing both sides by $x$. Then we get
$$
x+1=0
$$
and so $x=-1$. But quadratic equations are meant to have two solutions! One of them was lost along the way because when you divided by $x$, you did not consider what might happen if $x$ was equal to $0$. The same principle applies here. Dividing both sides by $\cos x$ is only valid when $\cos x \neq 0$, since division by zero is undefined. When you blindly divide both sides by $\cos x$, you are ignoring this fact. If you insist upon dividing by $\cos x$, then you can split the problem into two cases: (a) if $\cos x = 0$, and (b) if $\cos x \neq 0$. When dealing with case (b), we can then safely divide by $\cos x$. But this method is more cumbersome than factoring.